# Give a far-away player an effect

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

There are ways to detect if a player is far from a command block or villager but how do you give an effect to a player who leaves a certain radius from another player?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: Ive tried using testfor and using @e with players and a few other methods but they havent been giving any good signs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're gonna need execute for this one. Execute a command on the first player that selects the nearest player outside your radius and gives them the effect.

```
execute player_who_gives_others_the_effect ~0 ~0 ~0 effect @p[rm=5,c=1] minecraft:nausea
```

rm = minimum radius

c= count

This command gives the player outside the radius nausea. Find the other effects here: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Data_values#Status_effects

Comment: Ive tried changing it around a bit but it fails at the effect, I cant seem to change anything to fix it but thank you for the most part, it may just be that Im using 1.8 though